# interpolating data in a nested loop

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I am trying to use the numpy `interp` function in a loop to fill a 3D matrix, as shown below.

```py
for m in range(1,33): 
    for k in range(1,193): 
        for l in range(1,289): 
            U_v32[m,k,l] = np.interp(plev[m,k,l],PS_reg_v72[:,k,l],U_reg_v72[:,k,l])
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Code/regrid.py", line 147, in <module>
    U_v32[m,k,l] = np.interp(plev[m,k,l],PS_reg_v72[:,k,l],U_reg_v72[:,k,l])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in interp
  File "~/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1595, in interp
    return interp_func(x, xp, fp, left, right)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

I do not see why it gives me this error when I am already providing 1D arrays using the 3 nested loop.

Comment: Would you provide the shapes or your arrays: plea, PS_reg_v72, U_reg_v72

Comment: I suspect that the 3 input to np.interp have wrong shapes as they all must 1D arrays

Comment: plev is (32,192,288), PS_reg_v72(1,72,192,288) and U_reg_v72(1,72,192,288) ... And now I notice that I should have defined PS_reg_v72[0,:,k,l],U_reg_v72[0,:,k,l].

Comment: Okay then would you check your code again if it is working

Answer (score 0):

It looks that doing this modification works better:

```
for k in range(1,193): 
    for l in range(1,289): 
        U_v32[m,k,l] = np.interp(plev[m,k,l],PS_reg_v72[:,k,l],U_reg_v72[:,k,l])
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to make np.interp run faster